# Update value from inputText

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm working with ADF BC and I have several inputTexts.
Let's say I have the folowing scenario:

Step 1: inserting 1, 2, 3 in three different inputTexts (it1, it2 and it3, all three with autoSubmit == true).

Step 2: Click a button who calls the following method:

```
    public String aplicarFiltro() {
        Object it1param = null, it2param = null, it3param = null, sos1param = null;
        Parametros_IndicadoresLoadAll pila = Parametros_IndicadoresLoadAll.getInstance();
        pila.clear();
            if(it1.getValue() == null || it1.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
                it1param = "";
            } else {
                it1param = it1.getValue();
                if(it2.getValue() == null || it2.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    it2param = "";
                } else {
                    it2param = it2.getValue();
                    if(it3.getValue() == null || it3.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        it3param = "";
                    } else {
                        it3param = it3.getValue();
                    }
                }

            }

            if(sos1.getValue() != null) {
                sos1param = sos1.getValue();
            }
        pila.init(it1param, it2param, it3param, sos1param);
        if (it1.getValue() == null || it1.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
            showPopup(p1, true);
   /*      } else if (sos3.getValue() == null) {
            showPopup(p2, true); */

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Step 3: I erase the values from it2 and it3, I click the button again and call the same method. However, the value from it2 and it3 stays the same.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to re-think your approach: instead of doing the business in backing beans, try to use BC layer. So you can move the method

public String aplicarFiltro() {..} into Application Module Impl.
There, programatically get a reference to your VO's current Row and read the attribute's values.

First, test your scenario (your method) from BC Tester. Then, you can expose the method through bindings, and call it from backing beans.
ALso, I would expose the RowImpl class for your VO and put some debug info into setIt1(), setIt2(), setIt3() attributes, to see how the change.

Remember, is always far more simple to manage your business on BC layer than managed beans. Stay away from JSF life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if more things are wrong. But you're only setting "i2param" to something other than null if i1 has a value and "i3param" to something other then null if i1 and i2 has a value.

So start with the following. Change this:

```
        if(it1.getValue() == null || it1.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
            it1param = "";
        } else {
            it1param = it1.getValue();
            if(it2.getValue() == null || it2.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
                it2param = "";
            } else {
                it2param = it2.getValue();
                if(it3.getValue() == null || it3.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    it3param = "";
                } else {
                    it3param = it3.getValue();
                }
            }

        }
```

to:

```
if(it1.getValue() == null || it1.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
    it1param = "";
} else {
    it1param = it1.getValue();
}

if(it2.getValue() == null || it2.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
    it2param = "";
} else {
    it2param = it2.getValue();
}

if(it3.getValue() == null || it3.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
    it3param = "";
} else {
    it3param = it3.getValue();
}
```

Comment: This won't fix my problem, but you're right. I need to be careful about that